# Find two strings in Sections in a test file and combine them into a single line

Tags: string, bash, text

I have a large vbs file with many Cases like this:

```
Case 1750 'School Name  
For Each Folder in SubFolders
    FolderName = Folder.Name 
    If ((FolderName <> "All Users") AND (FolderName <> "Public")) then
        CreateDeepFolders ("C:\Users\" & FolderName & "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\")
        Set MyFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\" & FolderName & "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites", True)
        MyFile.WriteLine("httpS://10.10.10.10/")
        MyFile.Close
    End If
Next
Set UrlLink = objShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Folders\Custodian Desktop\BAS.lnk")
UrlLink.TargetPath = "http://10.10.10.10/webstation/"
UrlLink.IconLocation = "C:\Windows\UI.ico"
UrlLink.Save
CopyLinkToFolders "C:\Folders\Custodian Desktop\BAS.lnk",3
```

I want to use Bash to get the 4-digit number from the first line of each Case and the IP address from the corresponding line further down. Each Case is the same number of lines long.
I want to use the two bits of info to compile a file with DNS record entries like this on each line:

```
local-data: "1750.bas.domain.net. IN A 10.10.10.10"
```

I've tried to use grep and gawk but, even though I can isolate one or the other of the pieces, I can't get them both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your problem completely, it is what I understand:

1. You want to grep two expressions (in two different). lines
   This is not possible with **grep** as **grep** is limited to lines. If you want to find expressions between lines you can use **sed**.
2. You want to combine those expressions

Solutions:

Use something like this

```
var1=`grep...` (for the case number)
var2=`grep....` (for the ip)
```

Then you can combine var1 with var2 `var1="$var1 $var2"` or use it in any other way that you want.

You can also use **sed**.

Comment: I tried using grep, but I have a whole lot of iterations of the Case section, and I need to create an output line for each one containing the number and the ip from each section. I tried something like: for s in `cat Install_BAS.vbs|grep "^Case " -A 12`;do c=`echo $s|grep "^[1-2]"`;$i=`echo $s|grep "MyFile.WriteLine("|gawk -F"/" '{print $3}'`;l="local-data: \" $c.bas.domain.net. IN A $i\"";echo $l;done

Comment: Will the 'read' command help me at all. Someone in #bash on Freenode suggested it.

Comment: I've never been very good with **sed**. I'll have to learn, I guess.

Comment: I got an answer `use read to process the input line-by-line. when you hit a line that starts with "Case", record the number and set a flag. while the flag is set, look for the line with the IP address. when you find it, write it to stdout along with the number you captured from the line with "Case". reset flag. start looking for "Case" again.` on Freenode. I'm not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: 1- If you use sth like 'var1=`grep -E "^Case.[0-9]{4}" <file name> | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}"`'
, then you'll get all of the IDs in var1. you can do the same thing for IPS.
2- Then iterate over the line of var1 and var2 and make your output.

Comment: OK. I've got the IDs in **var1** and the IPs in **var2**. How do I iterate and get the corresponding line in each variable for output?

Comment: var2=`grep -E 'MyFile\.WriteLine\(\"' <filename> | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'`

Comment: Now you can use                                                                                       1- 'var1=( $var1 )' to make it an array.                                                            2- 'echo ${#var1[@]}' to get the number of fields in your array.                 3- set a for loop to iterate.                                                                          4- inside the for loop access each member by its index (ie. '${var1[1]}', .... '${var1[n]}')

Comment: Thank you for the last piece of the puzzle. I've never done anything like this before, but it works.

Comment: `for c in {0..155};do echo "local-data: \"${arr1[$c]}.bas.domain.net. IN A ${arr2[$c]}\"";done`

Comment: I thought that arrays would be the answer, but I'd only read about them in a man page, never used them.

Comment: You are welcome. You can make your code improved by using sed (replacing 2 greps with 1 sed), if you have time. You can also  choose my answer if you think it is helpful (it gives me some points and help others if they have the same problem as you) & you can mark the useful comments.